# <td> focusin event .addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a data table with a column like this

This is my HTML

```
<td class="orders-options column-invoice">
    <strong>
        <a class="row-title" href title="View detail">78060</a>
    </strong>
    <div class="locked-info"></div>
    <div class="row-actions">
        <span class="edit">Edit</span>
        <span class="view">View</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

I would like to show certain options like, "Edit" or "View" when user mouse over . My plan is to addclass on  to  so that it's visibility: changes hidden; to visible; according to CSS file.

This is my JS

```
$("td.orders-options").focusin(function() {
  $(this).find(".row-actions").addClass('visible'); 
});
$("td.orders-options").focusout(function() {
  $(this).find(".row-actions").removeClass('visible'); 
});
```

However this doesn't seem to have any effect on html.
Also I'm curious if this function will change class only in the  that is focused or all  on other  that are not focused

Comment: It should be just mouseover and mouseout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` or simple `hover`.

```
$("td.orders-options").mouseenter( function() {
     $(this).find(".row-actions").addClass('visible'); 
}).mouseleave( function() {
     $(this).find(".row-actions").removeClass('visible'); 
});
```

Also instead of visibility, toggle `display` property in css. Because `visibility:hidden` will take space though it's hidden.

In terms of `hover`, it will be like:

```
$("td.orders-options").hover( function() {
     $(this).find(".row-actions").addClass('visible'); 
} ,function() {
     $(this).find(".row-actions").removeClass('visible'); 
});
```

> Update: Adding DEMO

```js
$("td.orders-options").hover( function() {
  console.log("Rias");
 $(this).find(".row-actions").addClass('visible'); 
} ,function() {
 $(this).find(".row-actions").removeClass('visible'); 
});
```

```css
.row-actions.visible {
  display: block;
}

.row-actions {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td class="orders-options column-invoice">
<strong>
    <a class="row-title" href title="View detail">78060</a>
</strong>
<div class="locked-info"></div>
<div class="row-actions">
    <span class="edit">Edit</span>
    <span class="view">View</span>
</div>
</td>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use `.hover()`.`.hover()` method specifies two functions to run when the mouse pointer hovers over the selected elements:

```
$("td.orders-options").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".row-actions").addClass('visible'); 
},function(){
  $(this).find(".row-actions").removeClass('visible');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily achieve your goal using toggelclass

```
$("td.orders-options").hover( function() {
     $(this).find(".row-actions").toggleClass('visible'); 
});
```